# Unwanted emails are sent from some exchange users

Tags: exchange, spam, malware

In our exchange environment some unwanted emails are sent from a few users to abnormal addresses with .xyz suffix.They stuck in queue as the destination server isn't available.
Affected users got emails from the same domains before but they didn't click on any link available in the email text.
What could be the reason of this issue and what would be the solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the messages go out have "Read:" at first of their subjects so the sender ask for read receipt and they go on behalf of the sender request.

Answer (score 1):

If the emails are going out as the user, then it is usually one of three things.

1. The user lied to you about clicking on the link in the email and there is malware on the machine.
2. The user lied to you about clicking on the link in the email and entered their username and password in to a box.
3. The user lied to you about about using a strong password, which has been guessed. The email they received was a test to see if the account was active and with no bounce back, the spammer started abusing the server using the user's credentials.

That may seem harsh on the end users, but in most cases it is a user error that is the cause.

Check the end user's mailbox sent items to see if the messages are there. Also look for rules to see if something is blocking the messages. However I expected it will be either the second or third in my list, because if malware got on to the machine they wouldn't use your Exchange server to send email.

The solution? Tell the users to stop lying to you, enforce a decent password policy and ensure that authenticated relaying isn't possible on your Exchange server from anything outside of your network.

Comment: Strong password policy is available already and I am completely sure about at least one of the users who is my boss and he is not an unaware amateur user.